# how to manage rest API timeouts in a mobile app?

Tags: angularjs, rest, cordova, ionic-framework, timeout

I am looking for methods and best practice concepts for managing app API timeouts.

My app communicates to my server API - and on occasion there are timeouts with `Status: -1` being reported via my app error reporting mechanism.  In particular, I have noticed that when a user experiences a single timeout, that user then has a multiple timeouts to the API even on different API calls.  Its like once it triggers, timeouts follow that user throughout the app.

In my situation there are two problems:  1.  Why the timeouts are happening and 2. How to manage them when they do occur.  #1 is proving to be elusive - timeouts could be one of 50 reasons and I am continue to try and improve on the error reporting to hone in on the specifics; but its still a challenging thing to solve.   So, I believe as long as timeouts occur, its even more crucial to manage them properly.

1. Should the app wait 3, 5 10 or more seconds and auto-retry the timed out API call again?  How many times should it auto-retry before you stop the cycle?
2. Are there methods or techniques that can better determine what caused the timeout?
3. What are best practices for this?

For alerting purposes, when my app detects an error or timeout, it does a stack trace or api call capture and reports that back to my server (via an API call).  What I find interesting with the API timeouts is that if the users gets 2, 3 or 4 timeouts in a row - the app will capture each one of them and send them as an API call to the server - but each of those `report the timeout` calls works without issue - thee app doesn't ever seem to timeout reporting the timeout.

There is no reason or rhyme to the timeouts either.  100 users doing the same API call with no issue, then a random timeout happens for user 101.  Another 200 user api calls with no issue and then another random timeout happens for another user on a different api call.  None of the timeouts are pointing anything specific on the back.  If it was always the same api call timing out I would have something to focus on, but its always seemingly random.

Here is my app standard call:

```
var headers = {
  'Pragma' : 'no-cache', 
  'Expires' : -1, 
  'Cache-Control' : 'no-cache,must-revalidate', 
  'Content-Type' : 'application/json',        
  'X-Requested-With' : 'com.myapp
 }

  function serverAPI(typeID,dataObj,eInfo) {
    var httpTimeout = 30 ;
    var baseUrl = "https://api.myapp.com/v1/index.php" ;
    var req = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: baseUrl,
      timeout:httpTimeout,
      headers: headers,
      data: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
    }
    var respStart = new Date().getTime();  //timestamp to track timeout
     return $http(req)
    .then(function(response){
      if (response.status == 200) {
        //
        // do stuff with success response
        //
      } else {
        // received an improper response from server
        var err = resError(req,response) ;
        err.callBack = "Success" ;
        throw err ;
      }
    },function(err) {
      err.callBack = "Error" ;
      throw err ;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      if (!err.callBack) {
        err.callBack = "Catch" ;
      }
      var res = {} ;
      res.success = false ;

      // check if session timed out, no response from server
      var respStop = new Date().getTime() - respStart ;
      if (respStop >= httpTimeout) {
        //session timed out
        eInfo.session = "Timed out" ;
        res.success = "timeout" ;
      }
      httpError(err,eInfo,dataObj) ;  // report error
      return res ;  // pass 'false' back to calling function
    });
  }
```

When the timeouts occur my server receives the following values:

```
  err.status = -1 ; //actual error thrown
  eInfo.session = "Timed out"  //custom error reporting object.
```

eInfo and dataObj contain all the original call parameters and data passed to the call.